# Image is not displaying in email template on 2nd time forward

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, email-templates, massmail

Good day Friends,

I've a mass mailing program with simple mail templates (HTML and few Images). I've a problem with image display. My clients are not getting images in the mail. Sometimes they get a mail with all the images, But if they forward the same email to someone else, they can’t get the images in forwarded mail.

I really don’t know what’s happening with the approach., most of the cases the 2nd time forwarded mail is not showing the images properly.

For example, **consider I send a mail to client A**,

Here, Client A will get a mail with Images. Further, If Client A forward the same message to Person B then Person B is not getting Images in the Forwarded email.
I’m using the following Approach to Embed an image in the mail template:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" <some html content> <img src=\"cid:main.png\"  alt=\"\" border=\"0\" usemap=\"#Map\"> </html content ends here>");

Attachment imgMain = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("main.png"));
imgMain.ContentId = "main.png";
MailMessageObject.Attachments.Add(imgMain);
```

Instead of attachment, I tried bypassing the Image path from server directly. Something like as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" <some html content> <img src=\"www.mydomain.com/images/main.png\"  alt=\"\" border=\"0\" usemap=\"#Map\"> </html content ends here>");
```

But, result is same, Please help to resolve this problem